# Moving edges and vertices UVs on one half of an objects UV map

Tags: uv, vertices, transforms, edges

I am trying to straighten the UVs of one half of my pegboard, but I can't straighten the edges without it interfering with the other UV half of the pegboard.  I did all this in Maya and I no longer have it, so I had to do it here cause the textures became extremely warped.  What can I do to fix this?[image]

Comment: On UV editor, set "Sticky Selection Mode" dropdown to "Disabled".

Comment: I don't know where the UV editor in Blender 9.3 is.  Can you send an image?

Comment: The UV editor viewport is what you're showing in *your* pic, just cropped.

Comment: Sorry, I just don't see the option anywhere.

Comment: It's the icon with the dropdown arrow just to the left of the View menu on the UV editor toolbar.